# Why does jGit RemoteAdd command not chain like the others?

Tags: jgit

I have recently been using jGit and I noticed that the `RemoteAddCommand` doesn't use a chainable model like the other commands.

```java
// doesn't compile because setName returns void
git.remoteAdd().setName('other').setUri(new URIish(destUri)).call()
// works fine   
 git.push().setRemote('other').setPushTags().setPushAll().setProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor()).call()
```

The APIs seem so consistent otherwise (and stable) that it's hard to imagine this was an oversight. What was the design thinking here? or was it an oversight?

Comment: I can't find a reasoning in the documentation hence I would assume that it is an oversight.

Comment: The best audience to clarify this is perhaps the JGit developers mailing list: https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/jgit-dev

Comment: I was pending an accept to that group. But, I thought asking here could be lighter weight. It's not crucial enough to me to chase down an answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already got the answer from JGit malling list: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jgit-dev/msg03705.html. I just repost the thread here, so that others can see it:

> This was fixed by https://git.eclipse.org/r/c/123762/ (Chain RemoteAddCommand methods, 2018-05-30) and the fix is part of JGit 5.0 and newer.

So using JGit 5.0+ will work.

Comment: I did - but the answer lead to another question in my case (nothing related to git) - I had declared that I wanted version 5 - but upon inspection it was using 4.x - no idea.